# Cycle through <select> / <option> list and collect values with PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html-select, selected

I have a set of `<option>` inside a `<select>` and want to use JavaScript to remove all values that have been selected, put them into a string then post it to my PHP script.

Comment: What does this mean "i have a set of inside a"? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only Javascript/DOM
I'm guessing the `select` has multiple attribute

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById( 'myselect'); // your select element
var strSelection = ''; // string to store the selected stuff
for( let count = 0, limit = selectElem.options.length; count < limit; count++) //check every option
     if( selectElem.options[count].selected) // check if it's selected
         strSelection += selectElem.options[count].value + ','; // Concat to string and add delimiter, string format is up to you, here i add the .value but could also be .text or both..
selectElem.selectedIndex = -1; //Resets the selection element so all options are unselected
```

Answer (score 2):

I have wrote an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7eDgE/) using jQuery, because it makes the solution very simple.

```
var str = "";
// iterates over all selected options and generates the value-string.
$('#id option:selected').each(function(k,el) {
   str += $(el).val()+', ';
});

// removes all selected options
$('#id option:selected').remove();
```

To send the data to the server look at these jQuery functions: [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).